# mx Text not centering in bordercontainer

Tags: flash, apache-flex, text, centering, border-container

So I have a borderContainer and have a text in it and the text is always moved 2 - 4 pixels to the left, I need it perfectly centered.

code

```
<s:BorderContainer id="box" width="100%" borderWeight="0"
backgroundColor="0xffffff" borderVisible="false"
backgroundAlpha="1" horizontalCenter="1" textAlign="center">

<mx:Text id="text" fontSize="10" textAlign="center"
width="100%"/>

</s:BorderContainer>
```

I have tried everything to the text horizontalCenter and verticalCenter = 0 , 1 , middle , center  also tried removing 100 % doing all sort of things online but just can't get it to center perfectly :)
any help would be appreciated

Note: the text will be numbers like $19.99 or similar :)

Comment: Could you please explain what you want to get? Would you like to have just a border around the text block?

Comment: NO borders as you see the bordercontainer border is zero
I just want to center the text in the middle ... now its not centering its moved to the left around 3 - 4 pixels

Answer (score 0):

Can it help you?

```
<s:Group x="100" y="200">

    <s:Label  
        text="$19.99" 
        textAlign="center" 
        height="20" 
        width="55" 
        paddingTop="5" 
        paddingLeft="5" 
        paddingRight="5" 
        paddingBottom="5"/>

    <s:Rect width="100%" height="100%">
        <s:stroke>
            <s:SolidColorStroke color="red"/>
        </s:stroke>
    </s:Rect>
</s:Group>
```

I have added a Rect to show you the real border.

Comment: Are you sure? I have tried it with "-------" to see if it is centered. By me it is centered perfectly. May be we are talking about different things?

Comment: my question is not a group and a label, bordercontainer and a text. trying replacing the text with a label , didnt fix it . and no paddings and width is 100 %

Answer (score 0):

What version of flex do you use?
I've just tried your example(only replaced white background to red one to clearly see centering), and centering is perfect[image: BorderContainer with mx:Text inside. 8px to left border and 8px to right border]

I used flex 4.6.
However, I may advise you to embed that font which you use with mx:Text - for many fonts text measuring is not correct until those fonts are embedded.